# Match numerical data points with pre-defined grid

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods

I have data from some experiment that should resemble a known grid-structure. However, the data

- is off by some unknown angle
- is distorted in an unknown way
- may contain some displaced points

For an example, please have a look at this picture:
[image: Distorted grid]

As you can see, the (nice looking) grid is distorted (the angle between the red indicators I drew is not 90deg) and is also rotated a little bit (the horizontal red line is not really horizontal). In addition, on rhe right top and bottom you can see some defects of the structure.

Are there tools I could use to match the data to some grid that I define and thereby find out the corrected data point positions? If not, could you give me some hints to appropriate algorithms to accomplish this? I have googled and thought for a while, but did not come up with a nice (and simple) solution.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an (at least mostly) continuous transform that maps 2D points to 2D points -- e.g. a function f(x, y) that returns (x', y') with the property that, if this is done for every black dot (x, y) on your graph, the resulting set of (x', y') points will be a nice regular grid.  I'm not an expert, but to me this sounds a bit like image registration.